# How to get the running status of solr using solrj/ java code

Tags: solr

I need the status about if solr has started running, whether the indexing is going on or it has been stopped unexpectedly or finished. Also about the results of the query I have given. Like that for every action performed there in the interface, I need to know it via java code.

Answer (score 0):

To check Solr is running, whether solr is responding.
You can use the ping service of solr

[refer solr ping](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/ping.html)

Comment: It returns error that the request handler is not written. Where is to be written onto ? Also how to periodically check the indexing status in solr ?